# Access GridViewColumnHeader object from GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, string, object, header, gridviewcolumn

is it possible in wpf to access the header of a gridviewcolumn as gridviewcolumnheader?

I have an object:

```
GridViewColumn column;
```

But the "Header" property just returns a string (header text) not the "real" header object.

Can anyone help my?

Comment: Why do you want to access it?

Comment: To set a sort direction symbol (arrow) into the header using AdornerLayer

Answer (score 3):

I am myself very inexperianced with WPF... however it appears that that if you you do not define a GridViewColumnHeader, then you will not be given one when accessing .Header.

That is to say, if you define your GridViewColumn as:

```
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="stringColumn">
                    stringColumn.Header will return a string
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Then calling stringColumn.Header will return a string... however if you define it as say:

```
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="gridViewColumnHeaderColumn1">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader>
                        gridViewColumnHeaderColumn.Header will return a GridViewColumnHeaderColumn
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Then checking gridViewColumnHeaderColumn.Header will return a GridViewColumnHeaderColumn

Answer (score 2):

I've summarized different ways to find GridViewColumnHeader from GridViewColumn here: http://apaers.com/wpf-listview-access-gridviewcolumnheader-from-gridviewcolumn/

Comment: Thanks. Your idea was slick! I used it to implement "AllowResize" on selective ListView columns.

Comment: Link now broken. *sadface*